# Spring Freemarker Configuration, Template path

Tags: spring, configuration, freemarker

I have the following configuration which works. Now our clients want to customize these mail templates. Because we try to delivery an war file to several customers and dont want to override the changes they make in these templates. So I am thinking we may need to put the mailTemplate folder under Tomcat Root or somewhere else, just not inside the webapp.
I tried to change the value of templateLoaderPaths to something like this: 
   `value="../mailTemplate"`, 
    but it did work.
Please help. Thanks.

```
<bean id="freeMarkerConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
        <property name="templateLoaderPaths"
            value="/WEB-INF/mailTemplate/" />
        <property name="freemarkerSettings">
            <props>
                <prop key="template_update_delay">1800</prop>
                <prop key="default_encoding">UTF-8</prop>
                            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the full file path to the template directory as a "file:" URL, like

```
<property name="templateLoaderPaths" value="file:///path/to/mailTemplate/" />
```

Comment: if  I use `< value="file:///C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/mailTemplate/" />`, it works. But I cannot force my clients where to install tomcat, so how to use the relative path?  my webapp is here `< C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\myapp >`. Thanks

Comment: Hmm yes, interesting question. Never tried a relative path, not how that would be interpreted, i.e. as relative to which other directory? The working directory of the Tomcat process.

Comment: What should probably work too is to use a property placeholder in the path like value="${templateRootDir}" and set a Java system property with that name in the Tomcat. Then your customers could put those templates to wherever they wanted and just tell your application where they are by setting this property in their Tomcat startup script.